# List of all the symbols in namespace std

Tags: c++

Where can i find a list of all the symbols declared in the namespace std?

I really cannot find it, I don't know where to look for.

Comment: I'm fairly sure such a list would be specific to your STL version. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: Is there a tool to process header files and give you that list?

Comment: Why do you need this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @user267885 There is a way. It is called parsing. Very good idea as I can't find a ready made list online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of them, but you can start [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/).

Answer (score 6):

It's not complete yet, but cppreference is working on building such a list.
See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/symbol_index

Comment: Note that "std" is not apart of the list.